# Angular 6/CLI ng serve does not load polyfills for internet explorer

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular6, polyfills

I have an Angular 6 app built with the CLI. If I export for production using ng build --prod all is good and it works although I have some bugs unrelated to this issue.

However, if I try to use ng serve nothing works in internet explorer. It would help a lot being able to check out if the fixes have worked without having to run ng build --prod everytime I want to check something in IE.

So far:

- Looked on google in gneral
- Looked on stackoverflow suggestions
- Looked on Github related to angular CLI
- Tried a few flags like --live-reload false
- Cloned the repository again and ran a fresh install of dependencies (yarn install) to make sure I'm not missing things due to some conflicts or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up running `ng serve --prod` and in this instance everything works but it's also very slow. Would like to find a solution to it in general but I guess it's better than running ng build --prod everytime and looking at the files in the dist folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can use configurations part file from your angular.json with -c and your specific production config.

- ng serve adminapp --prod -c *yourConfig*

Tested on angular 6.1.4